Populate form with custom data Ws-Form
In wordpress I have a custom post type called 'break'. In that post type there are an ACF repeater field 'kort' with a sub field 'spiller'.
I would like the items from the repeater to be used in a Ws-form in Wordpress as a dropdown selection on a post template.
I have solved the first part of marking a function that put data (option 1) in a selector.

   // Add filter to change form ID 123 prior to rendering
  add_filter('wsf_pre_render_2', 'my_pre_render_2');

  // My function for filter wsf_pre_render_123
  function my_pre_render_2($form) {

    // Get select field ID: 321
    $field = wsf_form_get_field($form, 21);
      
    // Clear the rows in the select field
    wsf_field_rows_clear($field);
    // Create a new select row
    $row = (object) array(
      // Set row default parameter (Sets this row as selected)
      'default' => true,
      // Add one column to the row data
      'data' => array('Option 1')
    );
    // Add the row to the select field
    wsf_field_row_add($field, $row);
   
// Return the form
    return $form;
  }

```

But now I need the repeater to spit out an array of the field data for the current post. 
And I can't get it working 

